# Match to find a date in a list yields different answers depending on the formatting of the dates

Tags: excel, vba, date, match

I have a list of dates (work days, no weekends) on column A that is sorted in ascending order. The column has a string header that reads "Dates." The format of the column is m/d/yyyy.
The first date is 5/28/1998 on cell A2.
The last date is 2/9/2023 on cell A6216.

I have a date 6/28/1999 on cell AG275. I need to find the row for that date on column A.

This code finds the date, as long as both column A and cell AG275 are formatted as General.
In that case, cell AG275 reads as 36337 and the answer (variable a in the code below) returns 275, which is the row where 36337 is.

```vb
Sub findDate()
    
    Dim dateToFind
    Dim arr()
    Dim Rng As Range
    
    dateToFind = Cells(275, "ag").Value
    
    Set Rng = Worksheets("calcSheet").Range("A1:A6216")
    
    arr = Rng
 
    a = WorksheetFunction.Match(dateToFind, arr, 1)
 
End Sub
```

The problem is that if both column A and cell AG275 are formatted as short date then the code answer (variable a) is not 275 but 1530, which is 6/25/2004, which in General formatting is 38163 (the following date on cell A1531 is 6/28/2004).

I could add code to reformat everything before starting the code and work with numbers instead of dates, but I'd rather work with the given dates.

How can I get the answer if everything is formatted as short dates?

I suspect the problem may have to do with the way I am declaring the variables and the array. I tried declaring as Date, as Variant, as Long and as Integer.

I also tried, as I read in related posts,

```vb
dateToFind = CDate(Cells(275, "ag").Value)
```

and

```vb
dateToFind = CLng(CDate(Cells(275, "ag").Value))
```

The behavior is the same for long dates (mm/dd/yyyy).

Comment: Use [.Value2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Value2) and CDbl. `arr = Rng.Value2:  a = WorksheetFunction.Match(CDbl(dateToFind), arr, 1)`

Answer (score 1):

No mater the formatting if the content of the cells are dates and the content of the cell to find is a date, the following will work:

```
Sub findDate()
    
    Dim dateToFind As Variant
    Dim Rng As Range
    
    dateToFind = Cells(275, "ag")
    
    Set Rng = Worksheets("calcSheet").Range("A1:A6216")
    a = Application.Match(CLng(dateToFind), Rng, 1)
 End Sub
```